# Why does RVM give me a 'release candidate' when I ask for v2.1.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
rvm install 2.1.0
```

That command installs `ruby-2.1.0-rc1` on my system.

But the [Ruby website](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) says that v2.1.0 (final) is available, and is the current stable version. Why isn't RVM giving me that?

Comment: I guess, it is because it has found compiled ruby for your system, and it just installs the ruby without recomlitation, try to bypass it with: `rvm install 2.1.0p0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that your RVM installation is outdated.  RVM must be updated before you can install new rubies:

For example, `rvm list known` on my system showed me this:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
[ruby-]2.1.0-preview1
[ruby-]2.1.0-head
ruby-head
```

After updating with `rvm get head` it showed me this:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p484]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p353]
[ruby-]2.1.0
[ruby-]2.1-head
ruby-head
```

Try updating rvm and see if that fixes the problem